# Dynamically Pass attributes to SAML from Lightning Component/VF Page

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, saml, identity, identity-provider

I have a use case where a user clicks the SSO link on a case record or account record and it should pass some Case/Account fields based on the current record information to the SAML response. In other words, I want to append SAML parameters with Case.eID__c for example. That way, the remote report would display only information relevant to the current account the user is viewing.

I tried many approaches, read many forum posts with no success.

I tried customAttributes method on the Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin class (extending the class and overrding the method), like described in this documentation: ConnectedAppPlugin Class. It works but I am not able to query those values to customAttributes method as I need to pass the current record's ID to the method. So I want help in figuring out as to how I can pass that ID.

The custom attributes that we can add declaratively to the connected app are not helpful in my case, they only get information about the environment or the current user

Comment: You can't pass info to the plugin. The best you can do is prepare the data by writing it somewhere in such a way that the plugin can then query it based on the User id. If you're going that far, you might as well use the out of the box facility as the referenced answer shows.

Comment: I cannot write the data on an object and then query based on UserID, reason being, user can visit multiple pages and can perform multiple clicks, maintaining the state of a user for every click would be too many DMLs on that object

Comment: You can write it to a custom metadata or a custom setting or any custom object. One row per click, for example..then have your plugin figure out which one is the most recent click (row) to grab. Having said that, agreed that you need to rethink your architecture. SAML is not a good fit for this use case.